# How can I interrupt a calculation without aborting it?

Tags: evaluation, debugging

Before version 10.0, there was a menu item, Evaluation → Interrupt Evaluation..., which could be used to interrupt a calculation without aborting it.  It would bring up this window:

[image]

It was possible to [enter a subsession](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Dialogs.html), examine the kernel state, then resume the calculation using `Return[]`.

How do I access this functionality in version 10.0 or later?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The menu item is gone, but the functionality is still there in version 11.0.

It can be accessed by a keyboard shortcut:

- Command-Option-`.` on OS X
- Alt-`,` on Windows and Linux

The [front end token](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FrontEndTokens.html) is called

- `"EvaluatorInterrupt"`

It can be used e.g through a palette button.

Alternatively, use Evaluation → Evaluate in Subsession for similar functionality.  E.g.,

```
Table[Pause[1]; i, {i, 30}]
```

Now enter `i` and evaluate it using the above menu item before the `Table` has finished running.  You will see the current value of `i`.