# Commands to stop and continue evaluation without Debugger

Tags: notebooks

I would like to stop the evaluation somehwere at a specifiy line in a notebook.
Then I could for example check the state of some variables.

After that I would like to continue the evaluation from the position where it was stopped.

Is this possible without using the Debugger?

Comment: @Szabolcs Dialog[] is well-known. I use it often. Little known is `Debug[ expr1;  expr2; ... ]`, unfortunately it does not work in the Notebook interface, only in a terminal interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Dialog[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dialog.html) to interrupt and `Return[]` to resume.

Tutorial is here:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Dialogs.html

See also:

- [How can I interrupt a calculation without aborting it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131786/12)
- [How to pause a running evaluation (and continue it later)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135876/12)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then the Debugger is implemented by using `Dialog` only that he has a sophisticated way of inserting the breakpoints into the box-structure and a lot of functions to inspect the current stack. But I'm not entirely sure. I believe at some point I investigated in this.