# Accessing sowed data during long computation

Tags: evaluation, sow-reap

This question is very similar to the one posted here: [Interrogating a running evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178784/interrogating-a-running-evaluation?noredirect=1&lq=1) but my running computation consists of a backtracking procedure which sows valid solutions. It is hard to tell when the computation will be over so I would like to take a look at the results Sow'ed so far. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to get what you want with the built-in `Reap` and `Sow`.

However, here is a drop-in `Reap` - `Sow` replacement based on `` Internal`Bag `` structure, which is also the one that the actual `Reap` and `Sow` are based on:

```
SetAttributes[withSideEffect, HoldRest];
withSideEffect[code_, sideEffectCode_] := (sideEffectCode; code);

$storage = <||>

ClearAll[reap]
SetAttributes[reap, HoldFirst]

reap[expr_] := reap[expr, _]
reap[expr_, patt_] := reap[expr, patt, #2&]

(call : reap[expr_, patt_, func_]) /; !TrueQ[$inReap] :=
   Block[{$storage = <||>, $inReap = True},
    call
  ]

reap[expr_, patt:Except[_List], func_:Function[#2]] := 
  MapAt[First, reap[expr, {patt}, func], 2]

reap[expr_, patt_List, func_] :=
  Module[{result = expr, reaped, tag, matchingTags},
    {reaped, matchingTags} =
      Reap[
        Map[
          With[{matchingTagsData = KeySelect[$storage, MatchQ[#]]},
            Sow[Keys @ matchingTagsData, tag];
            Composition[
              KeyValueMap[func],
              Map[Internal`BagPart[#, All]&]
            ] @ matchingTagsData
          ]&
          ,
          patt
        ],
        tag
      ];
      If[matchingTags =!= {},
        KeyDropFrom[$storage, First @ matchingTags];
      ];
      {result, reaped}
  ]

ClearAll[sow, $globalTag]
sow[expr_] := sow[expr, $globalTag]
sow[expr_, _] /; !TrueQ[$inReap] := expr
sow[expr_, tags_List] := First @ Map[sow[expr, #]&, tags]
sow[expr_, tag_] := withSideEffect[expr,
   If[!KeyExistsQ[$storage, tag],
    $storage[tag] = Internal`Bag[{expr}],
    (* else *)
    Internal`StuffBag[$storage[tag], expr]
  ]
]


ClearAll[getCurrentData]
getCurrentData[part: _Integer | {__Integer} | _Span | All : All] := 
  getCurrentData[part, $globalTag]

getCurrentData[part: _Integer | {__Integer} | _Span | All : All, tag_] := 
  Replace[
    Lookup[$storage, tag, {}],
    bag: Except[{}] :> Internal`BagPart[bag, part]
  ]
```

It can serve as an explanation of how `Reap`-`Sow` work, but it can also be used to access the sowed data at any time, something that built-in `Reap`-`Sow` can't do:

```
reap[
  sow[1, {h[1], h[2], g[1]}];
  sow[2, g[2]];
  Print["The current data for tag ", h[1], " is ", getCurrentData[h[1]]];
  sow[3, {h[1], g[2], g[3]}]
  , 
  {_h, _g}
  , f
]

(*

 During evaluation of In[283]:= The current data for tag h[1] is {1}

 {3, {{f[h[1], {1, 3}], f[h[2], {1}]}, {f[g[1], {1}], f[g[2], {2, 3}], f[g[3], {3}]}}}
*)
```

In terms of performance, these will be slower, but should not be too much slower than the built-ins, since they are based on the same underlying data structure.

Comment: Nice approach (and upvote). Also can be done using `ResourceFunction["ExpressionBag"]`. The main advantage to this is that documentation is available.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. I was not aware of that one. But I have looked through the code of that one, and there is considerable difference. That one is basically a wrapper on top of expression bag structure. My code is a drop-in replacement for `Reap` / `Sow` (so, I don't need almost any documentation :).). I don't really expose expression bag here at all, and could in principle use different means to accumulate results .  So my code is really solving a different (but related) problem. It  is also several times shorter :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Also, quite frankly, that particular implementation doesn't strike me as exceptional - I see lots of bloat for very little added substance (w.r.t. the raw ``Internal`Bag`` API).  Also, some really important points seem to have been missed there, for example that the original ``Internal`Bag`` is automatically garbage-collectable and thus does not require manual resource management - which is a big deal in practice, and is not the case for the `ExpressionBag` wrapper.