# How do the functions Reap and Sow actually work behind the scenes?

Tags: performance-tuning, implementation-details, sow-reap

I have read that using Reap and Sow to generate a list of unknown length is much more efficient than using AppendTo over and over. I believe AppendTo works by creating a new list that is one element longer than the given list, iterating over every element in the given list to add it to the new list, and then adding in the new element. Therefore, it makes perfect sense that using AppendTo is inefficient for long lists. **But how do Reap and Sow do it better?**

The documentation says that Sow[e] "specifies that e should be collected by the nearest enclosing Reap".
My best guess is that Sow appends e to a linked list, and Reap converts this to an array–type list at the end. Is this correct? **How does the program keep track of the values that Sow specifies should be collected?** It has to store it *somehow*.

In addition, if you evaluate an expression that has Sow in it and do not enclose this in a Reap[], does the information that Sow generates get thrown out, is it not generated in the first place, or is it retained in some hidden way so that if that result is passed to Reap, Reap returns the same thing it would if it was given the unevaluated expression?

Comment: "How does the program keep track of the values that Sow specifies should be collected?" A hash table or maybe a simple linked list.

Comment: It's retained hidden in the return somehow which is why `y = Sow[1]; Reap[y]` works I think.

Comment: Some idea of how is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/574643)

Comment: The algorithms that Mathematica uses are rarely documented. Your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will make an exception to the usual practice I try to follow on this site, and fully replicate my post from [this answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210303/accessing-sowed-data-during-long-computation/210307#210307) here, since it answers this question just as directly or even more, than the one I originally posted it for. I hope this will not cause objections.

In addition to the standard `Reap` - `Sow` functionality, this one also allows access to intermediate accumulated results at any time during the execution - something that standard `Reap` - `Sow` don't.

---

Here is a drop-in `Reap` - `Sow` replacement based on `` Internal`Bag `` structure, which is also the one that the actual `Reap` and `Sow` are based on:

```
SetAttributes[withSideEffect, HoldRest];
withSideEffect[code_, sideEffectCode_] := (sideEffectCode; code);

$storage = <||>

ClearAll[reap]
SetAttributes[reap, HoldFirst]

reap[expr_] := reap[expr, _]
reap[expr_, patt_] := reap[expr, patt, #2&]

(call : reap[expr_, patt_, func_]) /; !TrueQ[$inReap] :=
  Block[{$storage = <||>, $inReap = True},
    call
  ]

reap[expr_, patt:Except[_List], func_:Function[#2]] := 
  MapAt[First, reap[expr, {patt}, func], 2]

reap[expr_, patt_List, func_] :=
  Module[{result = expr, reaped, tag, matchingTags},
    {reaped, matchingTags} =
      Reap[
        Map[
          With[{matchingTagsData = KeySelect[$storage, MatchQ[#]]},
            Sow[Keys @ matchingTagsData, tag];
            Composition[
              KeyValueMap[func],
              Map[Internal`BagPart[#, All]&]
            ] @ matchingTagsData
          ]&
          ,
          patt
        ],
        tag
      ];
      If[matchingTags =!= {},
        KeyDropFrom[$storage, First @ matchingTags];
      ];
      {result, reaped}
  ]

ClearAll[sow, $globalTag]
sow[expr_] := sow[expr, $globalTag]
sow[expr_, _] /; !TrueQ[$inReap] := expr
sow[expr_, tags_List] := First @ Map[sow[expr, #]&, tags]
sow[expr_, tag_] := withSideEffect[expr,
  If[!KeyExistsQ[$storage, tag],
    $storage[tag] = Internal`Bag[{expr}],
    (* else *)
    Internal`StuffBag[$storage[tag], expr]
  ]
]


ClearAll[getCurrentData]
getCurrentData[part: _Integer | {__Integer} | _Span | All : All] := 
  getCurrentData[part, $globalTag]

getCurrentData[part: _Integer | {__Integer} | _Span | All : All, tag_] := 
  Replace[
    Lookup[$storage, tag, {}],
    bag: Except[{}] :> Internal`BagPart[bag, part]
  ]
```

It can serve as an explanation of how `Reap`-`Sow` work, but it can also be used to access the sowed data at any time, something that built-in `Reap`-`Sow` can't do:

```
reap[
  sow[1, {h[1], h[2], g[1]}];
  sow[2, g[2]];
  Print["The current data for tag ", h[1], " is ", getCurrentData[h[1]]];
  sow[3, {h[1], g[2], g[3]}]
  , 
  {_h, _g}
  , f
]

(*

 During evaluation of In[283]:= The current data for tag h[1] is {1}

 {3, {{f[h[1], {1, 3}], f[h[2], {1}]}, {f[g[1], {1}], f[g[2], {2, 3}], f[g[3], {3}]}}}
*)
```

In terms of performance, these will be slower, but should not be too much slower than the built-ins, since they are based on the same underlying data structure.

Comment: I will be happy to expand on specific points of the above implementation which will cause questions or will be found hard to understand. Note also that while the above implementation uses actual `Sow` internally, this isn't critical and was only done as a short-cut, which one can in principle do without.

Comment: This is so slick we should all downvote it, and claim you had so many upvotes that the counter overflowed to negative.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks :). That's the most interesting praise I've got for a post during my entire presence here on this site :).

Comment: That's what happens when you mix admiration and envy...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau lol. I think this is mutual :)

Answer (score 18):

I do not know how `Sow` and `Reap` are actually implemented, but to show you that it isn't magic, I can provide the following toy implementation for you.

```
ClearAll[sow, reap];
sow[x_, tag_] := x;

SetAttributes[reap, HoldFirst];
reap[expression_] := Block[{sow, a},
  a = <||>;
  sow[x_, tag_] := With[{exp = x},
    If[
     MissingQ[a[tag]]
     ,
     AssociateTo[a, tag -> <|1 -> exp|>];
     ,
     AssociateTo[a[tag], Length[a[tag]] + 1 -> exp];
     ];
    exp
    ];
  {expression, Values /@ a}
  ]
```

Observe that `reap` locally overwrites the definition of `sow`. This way, `sow` will do anything nontrivial only if it is wrapped by `reap`. The accumulation can be done in any dynamic data type like a linked list or a hash table. I use a nested `Association` here, which is basically a hash table. Here is a simple usage example:

```
reap[
 Table[sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, 6}]
 ]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, <|1 -> {1, 4}, 2 -> {2, 5}, 0 -> {3, 6}|>}

You may compare the output of

```
Trace[
 Table[sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, 6}]
 ]
```

with

```
Trace[
 reap[
  Table[sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, 6}]
  ]
 ]
```

to see why this local redefinition technique makes sense. Well, this brought me to the idea to run

```
Trace[
 Reap[
  Table[Sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, 6}]
  ]
 ]
```

vs.

```
Trace[
  Table[Sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, 6}]
]
```

and there something surprising happens: The latter reveals that the trace is actually *longer* without `Reap` because some obscure `Message` passing is going on. `Message` is typically used for error handling and usually it is very, very slow. In indeed, for some reason, `Sow` without `Reap` is actually *slower* than with `Reap` oO

```
n = 100000;
Reap[data1 = Table[Sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, n}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
data2 = Table[Sow[i, Mod[i, 3]], {i, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
data1 == data2
```

> 0.087347
>
> 0.24273
>
> True

Comment: The last bit is a nice find. People, too, often work more efficiently and with less grumbling (= `Message`) if they feel there is some purpose to their work. :)

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher - That's a nice implementation, and if I can't get a less hypothetical answer, I will accept yours. Are you sure that Reap overwrites the definition of Sow? The fact that Sow is less efficient without Reap makes me think that it's not being overwritten.

Comment: No, as I said, I am not sure. It is also possible that `Sow` and `Reap` are not at all implemented in the language itsself, but rather on the "C-side". Moreover, one can nest `Reap`s in each other and IIRC `Sow` is supposed to be collected only in the most recent `Reap`. This is also not reflect in the implementation. As I said, it is just a toy model.

Comment: This was also quite nice. At one time I sometimes used hashing via pattern-free `DownValues` to emulate the functionality of expr bags. Those experiments long predate the appearance of `Association`.