# What happens if you don't Reap what you've Sown?

Tags: memory, implementation-details, sow-reap

As I understand it, when using `Sow[expr]` you throw the `expr` on some private stack which you can `Reap` afterwards.

**Questions:** But what happens if you don't `Reap`? Does the sowed data remain on this stack? Can this cause issues (memory leaks) if you sow large amounts of data?

Comment: Have you tested it yourself? This seems like you could try it out and see.

Comment: Try it, it does not increase the memory.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244017/how-do-the-functions-reap-and-sow-actually-work-behind-the-scenes

Comment: I thought this was going to be a biblical or philosophical question, when it appeared in the HNQ.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Preamble

This complements the answer of [Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26598/roman) with a few more details.

`Reap` - `Sow` implementation is based on an internal object `` Internal`Bag ``, which is properly garbage-collectable. Once an expression wrapped in `Reap`, where `Sow` has been internally used, goes out of scope, or its evaluation is finished, all these objects are GC-ed and the memory is released.

Also, whenever there is no `Reap` around `Sow`, no collection of sown values seems to be at all attempted, and no extra memory is used (i.e., `Sow` then acts like `Identity` or `#&`).

### Memory consumption measurements

#### `Reap` - `Sow` measurements

Let us now illustrate that. First, measure memory consumption for 3 cases: simple computation (idle function mapped on a large list), same with `Sow` in place of an idle function, and same with `Reap` wrapped around code with `Sow` inside:

```
ClearAll[$dataSize, data, wors, rwos, rws, storedBag]

$HistoryLength = 0;

$dataSize = 100000;
data = Range[$dataSize];
wors = MaxMemoryUsed[f /@ data] (* No Reap - Sow at all *)
rwos = MaxMemoryUsed[Sow /@ data] (* Sow without Reap *)
rwos - wors (* Possible extra memory used by Sow without Reap *) 
rws = MaxMemoryUsed[ Reap[Sow /@ data]] (* Sow with surrounding Reap *)
storedBag = rws - rwos (* How much memory take internal structures storing sown results *)

(* 
   7989840
   7990136
   296
   8856288
   866152
*)
```

The first conclusion we make, is similar to what Roman has stated: there is pretty much no memory wasted when `Sow` is used without `Reap` (difference is just a few bytes, `296` here) for even decently sized data.

The last value `866152` is what has been used to internally store sown data.

#### `` Internal`Bag[] `` measurements

Let us now experiment with the `` Internal`Bag[] `` structure:

```
bag = Internal`Bag[]; (* Initialize the bag *)
Do[Internal`StuffBag[bag, i], {i, data}]; (* Fill the bag with the same data *)
ByteCount[bag] (* Unfortunately, ByteCount does not give correct value for bags *)
mu = MemoryInUse[]; (* which is why here we measure the used memory using MemoryInUse *)
Remove[bag]
bagUse = mu - MemoryInUse[]

(*
    33
    866248
*)
```

The first number shows that `ByteCount` can not be trusted for bags.

#### Comparison

The second number we can compare to the value of `storedBag` variable, which we obtained earlier and in a completely different way:

```
bagUse - storedBag 

(* 96 *)
```

I wasn't able to track this remaining difference of 96 bytes down and explain it, but it stays fairly constant when we vary `$dataSize` within some range, and is a pretty small residual value, compared to the total amount of memory used.

**Please note**: when running the above code on a fresh kernel, you may need to ignore the first few runs, to start getting stable results similar to those I quoted above. The reason probably has to do with some initialization / autoloading process, although this is just a guess.

#### What happens if code inside `Reap` returns early

This has been asked in comments and is a good question. Here is an illustration:

```
rwsReturn = MaxMemoryUsed[
  Reap[If[# > $dataSize /2, Return[#, Reap], Sow[#]] & /@ data]
]; (* Sow with surrounding Reap, but exiting early *)

storedBagReturn = rwsReturn - rwos (* How much memory takes internal structures storing sown results *)

(* 434160 *)
```

In this case, I used a 2-argument `Return` to return early, but the same would've happened had I used `Throw` / `Catch` instead. What we see is that memory still has been filled with data up to the point of early return - we get almost exactly half the memory used in the full evaluation case, which is what we would expect here.

Here is a crude way to model how this works:

```
ClearAll[reap, sow, $storage, $inReap]
$inReap = False;
SetAttributes[{reap}, HoldAll]
reap[code_] := # &@ Block[
  {$inReap = True, $storage}, 
  {code, Internal`BagPart[$storage, All]}
]
sow[arg_] /; !TrueQ[$inReap] := arg;
sow[arg_] := If[ 
  ! ValueQ[$storage],  
  $storage  = Internal`Bag[{arg}]; arg,
  Internal`StuffBag[$storage, arg]; arg
];
```

The `# &@` part in `reap` implementation is needed if one wants to be able to use 2-arg `Return` on `reap`, otherwise one can remove it.

This gives exact same results:

```
storedBagReturn = MaxMemoryUsed[
  reap[If[# > $dataSize /2, Return[#, reap], sow[#]] & /@ data]
]
storedBagReturn = rwsReturn - rwos (* How much memory takes internal structures storing sown results *)

(* 
  8424264
  434160
*)
```

So, even though `Reap` has been interrupted and the sown results have been discarded as well as the result of evaluation, otherwise `Reap` - `Sow` work as usual. What matters is that `Reap` being wrapped around the code creates a dynamic environment in which `Sow` does collect the data, rather than being idle (which happens when there is no `Reap` around the code). Whether or not the evaluation is interrupted, does not affect the "collecting" vs "idle" mode for `Sow`.

### Summary

The above analysis indicates that:

- `Sow` without surrounding `Reap` does not use any noticeable extra memory (w.r.t. computations without `Sow`).
- Memory consumption of `Sow` with surrounding `Reap` is in good agreement with what one would expect based on the behavior of the underlying `` Internal`Bag[] `` structure.
- We have seen that bags are automatically GC-ed once not referenced, which explain why `Reap` and `Sow` behave the same.

Comment: My inference has been that `Reap[]` sets up bag(s) to store (appropriately tagged) objects. `Sow[]` looks for bag(s) in which to stuff an object. If there are no bags appropriate the (tagged) object, `Sow[]` does nothing.  And if nothing, then no memory is used. Perhaps I didn't read your answer carefully enough, but does my description seem an accurate model? -- Further, I'd assume `Sow[]` stores a pointer and itself has a minimal impact on memory. The real impact comes when `Reap` constructs the lists of sown objects; then objects might be copied or at least blocked from GC. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I can't think of anything wrong in your description. Of course, my guess here would be as good as yours, since I didn't see the internal code for `Reap`/`Sow`. My understanding is that when `Reap` is wrapped around, it sets some kind of dynamic `Block` - like environment, which tells `Sow` to create bag-based containers for intermediate results as needed (i.e. every time a new tag appears, a new container is created and starts populating). When the code inside `Reap` is done executing, `Reap` performs tag filtering and copies collected objects into lists, and then bags are released.

Comment: Substituting for `data`, ``Developer`FromPackedArray[data]``, `Table[Range[$dataSize], 10]` and `(a+b)^2000 // Expand` yields varying results for me that have me confused.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am getting the same results every time (for the last input I had to use `List @@ ((a+b)^2000 // Expand)` to run the bag measurement code which expects a list). But I forgot to set `$HistoryLength = 0` at the start of my post, while this setting is critical for correct measurements. Also, one has to ignore the first couple of runs of the code on a fresh kernel, since presumably some autoloading / nontrivial state changes take place. I am on Mac OSX, and use a pretty old build 12.1.1. on this machine.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I made changes to the answer, adding `$HistoryLength = 0` and mentioning that the first few runs of code might have to be ignored to reach stable results.

Comment: Here's the unpacked example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pa0F.png -- I may have just figured that one out (by giving `f` a definition): https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw5y9.png -- *Reply to new comment:* I noticed the need for some warm-up trials.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: if I would create a list using Reap[ Do[ Sow[ expr ] ... ] ] and Reap doesn't get evaluated because, e.g. of a throw statement inside expr, would that also count as Reap getting out of scope or its evaluation finishing?

Comment: @Gert That's a good question. I have added a new section to my answer, to address it. Check it out.

Answer (score 22):

It looks like there's no memory being used by `Sow` when there is no encompassing `Reap`.

#### With `Reap`

```
Exit[]
a = Reap[Do[Sow[i], {i, 2^28}]];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*    4532982944    *)
```

which is a reasonable amount of memory: 4 Gigabytes are required for 2^28 numbers taking 16 bytes each.

#### Without `Reap`

```
Exit[]
Do[Sow[i], {i, 2^28}];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*    69922256    *)
```

which is 70 Megabytes: there seems to be no storage of the sown numbers anywhere, not even a temporary storage.