# What Reap/Sow tricks do you use?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, expression-manipulation, sow-reap

I admit that I have been reluctant to use `Reap` and `Sow` for years and that I used it only when I had no choice with [`EvaluationMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html).

That is partly because the documentation was difficult for me and partly because I could not think of any scenario where that would be useful. My impression is that I am not the only one that avoids Reap/Sow constructs.

However, I am noticing that it can be useful. Here are some examples:

#### Sub expressions

Obtaining a list of sub-expressions :

```
Reap[expression /. 
  x : pattern :> Sow[x]]
```

Depending on the pattern that might differ from

```
Cases[expression,pattern,All]
```

**Example**:

```
Cases[{x, x^2, m[x]*m[y]*e}, m[a_]*m[b_], All]
```

`{}`

```
Reap[{x, x^2, m[x]*m[y]*e} /. x : m[a_]*m[b_] :> Sow[x]][[2, 1]]
```

`{m[x] m[y]}`

#### Substitution for [`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html).

Compare :

```
l = {};
Do[AppendTo[l, RandomReal[]], 10^5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

`10.8` seconds

with

```
l = {};
Reap[Do[Sow[RandomReal[]], 10^5]][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`0.06` seconds

`AppendTo` is slow because it copies the list each time. See the following links for further details on `AppendTo`:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72625/86543

and point 3 and 5 in this answer:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/86543

See also the following for a way to reproduce and enhance Reap/Sow:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244033/86543

#### `EvaluationMonitor` or `StepMonitor`

Nothing much to say other than check out the documentation but I am guilty of not using this to check why `FindRoot` or `Plot` is not converging or is slow.

#### Debugging

I use `Echo` usually but if one needs to extract a lot of intermediate parts in a code and check how they relate to each other using another code, then copy pasting Echo outputs would be overly complicated.

Also, `Reap` and `Sow` could be helpful to check what [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html), [`MapAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAll.html), [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) is working on especially if one included a level specification. That said, I prefer taking a small example and using [`Framed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html)

#### Finding specific terms using functions that take a function as an argument

For example one may have wrote a code that acts only on specific terms using a function argument. A quick way to extract those specific terms is to use `Reap` and `Sow`.

#### Arbitrary depth and position categorization

One can use Reap/Sow with tags in combination with [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html), [`MapAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAll.html),[`MapBlock`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapBlock.html), [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html), [`ArrayReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReduce.html) etc to generalize [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Gather`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gather.html) to different depths and positions.

**Example 1:**

Gather sub-expressions of an expression by LeafCount:

```
Reap[MapAll[Sow[#, LeafCount[#]] &, 
    Integrate[1/(1 + Tan[x]^20), x]]][[2]] // Map[DeleteDuplicates]
```

**Example 2:**

Gather and select columns of a matrix depending on whether the sum of elements of the column is prime:

```
(
Reap[
    ArrayReduce[
                Sow[{#,PrimeQ@Total@#}
                    ,
                    PrimeQ[Total@#]
                   ]&
        ,
        EchoFunction[MatrixForm]@
        Array[RandomInteger[40]&,{3,4}]
        ,
        1
    ]
][[2]]
//Map[MatrixForm,#,{2,Infinity}]&
)
```

The matrix:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 13 & 13 & 25 & 28 \\
 21 & 26 & 7 & 28 \\
 9 & 35 & 21 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

The gathered columns:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{\{13,21,9\},\text{True}\} & \{\{25,7,21\},\text{True}\} \\
 \{\{13,26,35\},\text{False}\} & \{\{28,28,4\},\text{False}\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

If we want to select only the column where the sum of elements is prime than we can add an extra argument True at the end in the `Reap` command.

I should also mention SelectEquivalents from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245166

but I am not sure how to use it in practice.

---

What else ?

Comment: Although I asked on Meta what the reasons for closing are I still do not see why these types of questions should be closed (and in my opinion closing is a bit excessively frequent recently). Yes it is broad and no it is not made to be specific. What are the alternatives and what is the gain/loss ratio for closing ? Reap/Sow gets little attention, asking users to just scroll through all of the posts on stack exchange is not a good alternative in my opinion and will just lead to more people fearful to use Reap/Sow. I fail to see how that is better for the community.

Comment: I'm no expert but it seems within scope, or at least I've seen similar questions/threads in past that were retained.

Comment: Usually, material like this is presented as a question/answer pair.

Comment: I find such open-ended discussions useful.  I often return to and refer my students to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users.  In general, I respect the opinions of frequent contributors.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I should move the list of uses/examples for Reap and Sow to an answer and leave only the question ?  I have two personal issues with that, 1 : that would double my points and I rather not get my reputation bloated by a single question/answer for which I placed little effort. I am actually already bothered by getting 6 points for a simple question.  I can separate the questions and examples more clearly in my question. 2: I feel it more prudent on my behalf to not attempt such an authoritative general answer for such a general question. I will appreciate any useful answer though.

Comment: If you feel more comfortable with your question/answer as it, stay with it.  However structured, it is useful.  (+!)

Comment: I just wanted to throw in my two cents on it as an improvement over AppendTo, which seems horrendously slow once you get a list of any size (I'm guessing Mathematica just re-copies the list every time by default?) So if you're going to be AppendTo-ing more than a few hundred times, I would Reap/Sow every time instead.

Comment: @Trev Indeed AppendTo copies the lists as lists are immutable in Mathematica here are some references: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72625/86543,  and point 3 and 5 in this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/86543

Comment: @Trev I added those links to the answer and a link that shows how to reproduce and enhance Reap/Sow (by being able to access the data stored at any time)

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you for mentioning why you vote to close. For me, finding sub-expressions with `ReplaceAll` and `Sow` and using `Sow` with tags as a generalized form of `Gather` and `Select` can be quite useful to know. There is another usage of `Reap` and `Sow` that someone could have included and that I did not which is:

Comment: `Reap[FullSimplify[expression,ComplexityFunction->(Sow[#];LeafCount[#] &)]` which I saw in another answer and which allows finding some of the steps of `FullSimplify`. But I did not  find a case where it was actually useful to me.

Comment: From a pedagogical standpoint I find it valuable as it shows examples of why one would use `Reap/Sow` when the documentation is difficult and people do not see the point of these functions : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181597/86543. Basically I think I would have been rather happy to find a post like this in the past when I avoided `Reap`/`Sow`.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'll bite. Here is one example where I found `Reap`/`Sow` useful.  It's also an excuse to document my `Backtrack` function that I find useful but hasn't seen many example of Wolfram Language code implementing it in a most generic form.

---

[Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) is a very useful technique for solving combinatorial problems, and Donald Knuth dedicated a substantial part of TAOCP 4A to it. Let's define a simple backtrack solver:

```
Backtrack[start_, next_, visitQ_, visit_] := Module[{
   level = 1, (* current search level *)
   stack = {{start}}, (* list of states to try at each level *)
   current = {1}, (* 
   list of indexes of states that need to be tried at each level*)
   state (* current state *)},
  While[level > 0,
   If[current[[level]] > Length[stack[[level]]], (* 
    We must backtrack *)
    level--,
    state = stack[[level, current[[level]]]];
    current[[level]]++;
    If[visitQ@state, visit@state];
    With[{nextStates = next@state},
     If[
      Length@nextStates > 0, (* We must go deeper one level *)
      level++;
      If[Length@stack < level, stack = Append[stack, nextStates], 
       stack[[level]] = nextStates];
      If[Length@current < level, current = Append[current, 1], 
       current[[level]] = 1]
      ]]]]]
```

The function `Backtrack` uses the following parameters:

- `start` - the initial state
- `next` - a function that, given the current state, produces a list of next states
- `visitQ` - a function that checks whether the current state should be visited
- `visit` - a function that visits the current state

It's the most generic version, and we can define more specialized versions with more convenient interface by modifying the `visit` function. Notice the use of `Reap`/`Sow` in `BacktrackCollect` - I find it idiomatic to use it for data collection, esp. given very non-linear nature of backtracking search.

```
BacktrackCollect[start_, next_, visitQ_, n_ : -1] := 
 Module[{count = 0, r},
  r = Reap@
    Catch@Backtrack[start, next, 
      visitQ, (Sow[#]; count++; If[count == n, Throw["Enough"]]) &];
  If[Length@r[[2]] > 0, r[[2, 1]], {}]]

BacktrackCount[start_, next_, visitQ_] := 
 Module[{count = 0}, Backtrack[start, next, visitQ, count++ &]; count]
```

---

Now let's use our freshly minted `BacktrackCollect` to solve n-queens problem:

```
queenProblem[n_] := Module[{next, visitQ},
  next[queens_] := Map[
    Append[queens, #] &,
    Select[
     Complement[Range[n], queens],
     q |-> Module[{m = Length@queens, i},
       AllTrue[Range[m], Abs[queens[[#]] - q] != m + 1 - # &]
       ]]];
  visitQ[queens_] := Length@queens == n;
  {next, visitQ}]

{next, visitQ} = queenProblem[5];

BacktrackCount[{}, next, visitQ] // Timing (* {0.003299, 10} *)

displayQueens[queens_] := Module[{n = Length[queens], board, i},
  board = ConstantArray[" ", {n, n}];
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   board[[queens[[i]], i]] = \[BlackQueen]];
  Grid[board, Frame -> All, 
   Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
     Flatten[Table[{i, j} -> 
        If[EvenQ[i + j], Darker[White], White], {i, n}, {j, n}]]}]]

Multicolumn[displayQueens /@ BacktrackCollect[{}, next, visitQ], 5]
```

[image]